# How to use tail in combination with sed .

Tags: bash

I want to beep a Sound ,  incase there is any Exception ocured in Log Files .

I am using bash script .

But unfortunately when tail is used in combintaion with sed , it doesn't work .

I have tried with the below commands and posting here .

```
tail -f mylogs.log | grep "Exception" | sed -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'



tail -f mylogs.log  | sed -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'



tail -f mylogs.log  | grep "Exception" | sed -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'
```

Comment: +1 for `$'` construct. I've never seen that before.

Comment: @AdrianPronk What does the `$'` construct mean?

Comment: @AlaaAli: It's a bash string that allows you to use c-style escapes such as `\a` for the bell character.  See the section on `QUOTING` in `man bash`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that `grep` sees that it's not writing to the terminal, so it buffers its output, eventually writing big chunks that `sed` can process all at once. To tell it to print out lines as soon as they're available, use the `--line-buffered` option:

```
tail -f mylogs.log \
  | grep --line-buffered Exception \
  | sed -u -e $'s/Exception/Exception\a/'
```

(Note that I've also added the `-u` flag to `sed`, which is similar to `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option. In my testing it didn't seem to make a difference for this command, but I figure it's better to include it just in case.)

Comment: Observation: `$'s/Exception/Exception\a/'` doesn't seem to changing the text but `$'s/Exception/Exception\\\a/'` is on my system.

Comment: @ruakh , I just tried the command , it just Logs the Text , but there is no sound . Do i need to make any settings ??

Comment: @another.anon.coward: `\a` is the alert (bell) character; it produces a beep, without affecting the visual appearance of the line.

Comment: @Kiran: That is a completely separate question. If `echo $'\a'` doesn't produce a beep for you, then yeah, that's probably a setting -- and this probably *isn't* the site to ask about it on.

Comment: Is grep really needed?: `tail -f mylogs.log | sed -u -ne $'/Exception/{;s/.$/&\a/;p;}'`

Comment: @William: That would work, too. But I think that, even among people who understand `sed s/x/y/`, there are more people who understand `grep x` than who understand `sed -n /x/p`. :-P

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! As you have noted I had totally got the Q wrong

Comment: While `sed -u` doesn't make a difference in this case, it is very useful if you want to pipe it to yet another program

Comment: Note: on MacOS there's `-l` instead of `-u`. Otherwise it works well.